# on stateChangeSuccess not working with Angular and Meteor 1.3.1

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular-ui-router, angular-meteor

I'm trying to make this function work with meteor 1.3.1 and it seems that it isn't working or I'm doing it wrong.

Here's my code:

```
import angular from 'angular';
import angularMeteor from 'angular-meteor';
import uiRouter from 'angular-ui-router';
import todosList from '../imports/components/todosList/todosList';
import navbar from '../imports/components/navbar/navbar';
import preloader from '../imports/components/preloader/preloader';

app = angular.module('exampleApp', [
  angularMeteor,
  uiRouter,
  todosList.name,
  navbar.name,
  preloader.name
]);

app.config(function($locationProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: "/",
      templateUrl: "client/home/home.html"
    })
    .state('contact', {
      url: "/contact",
      templateUrl: "client/contact/contact.html"
    })
    .state('login', {
      url: "/login",
      templateUrl: "client/login/login.html"
    });
})
  .run(function ($rootScope, $state) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (evt, toState) {
      console.log('test');
    });
  });
```

I've tried doing just `$scope` as well but no success whatsoever.

**QUESTION**

How do I get the `$stateChangeSuccess` functions to work with angular-meteor 1.3.1 and execute each time a state changes?